# creating a new column with logical values if value in another column > 0

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

New to R, so bear with me. I have a dataframe with values

```
x y
1 2
4 4
5 3
6 0
```

I want to create a third column that indicates with TRUE or FALSE whether a value in column y is 0.

```
x y z
1 2 TRUE
0 4 TRUE
5 3 TRUE
6 0 FALSE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `>` compares the lhs and rhs to get a logical vector.  By assigning the output as a new column ('z'), we create the new column in the original dataset 'df1'.

```
df1$z <- df1$y > 0
```

Comment: It worked! I was thinking too difficult, trying stuff with the ifelse function. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also always create one column with an "empty" value in order to avoid if-else loop.

Something like this could work as well (though the solution proposed above is of course better):

```
df$z <- "False"
df$z[df$y > 0] <- "True"
```

Quotes can be escaped if you wish a logical variable rather than a string

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that is faster (although this only becomes a critical issue when working with large datasets)

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)

df1[, z := y > 0]
```

Comment: This would work as well, data set is huge though. Thanks a lot for looking at my problem!

Comment: I doubt it would be noticeably faster with just one primitive computation.

Comment: I've checked here. It's a small difference indeed. Anyway, it's usually good to know alternative solutions to the same problem ;)