# R: Create new column with true/false if another column begins with "<"

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has a column like this:

```
x       
apple 
orange  
<pear> 
orange 
<straw-berry>
```

i would now like to add a new column that is populated with `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether the value of column `x` contains angle brackets, or e.g. starts with `<`:

```
x               y
apple           FALSE
orange          FALSE
<pear>          TRUE
orange          FALSE
<straw-berry>   TRUE
```

I have tried an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091133/creating-a-new-column-with-logical-values-if-value-in-another-column-0), but without success;

```
d$y<- "False"
d$y[d$x[grep('<', rownames(d$x)),]] <- "True"
```

I get an `incorrect number of dimensions` error with that code.

Comment: `d$y <- grepl("^<", d$x)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: The issue with your attempt is the comma after the grep. `d$y` isn't a data frame, it's a 1-dimensional column, but the `[ , ]` is trying to treat it like a 2-dimensional object. Delete that comma and your code will work fine. (Though using a logical `TRUE` is probably better than a string `"True"`. Also your code doesn't check if `x` *starts* with a `<`, it just checks if `x` *contains* a `<`.)

Comment: or `substr(df$x, 1, 1)=='<'`

Answer (score 1):

The `str_detect` from the `stringr` package returns TRUE/FALSE if the given string matches a pattern - here "<" :

```
df$y <- str_detect(x, "<")
```

Comment: This gives `TRUE` also for elements with '<' in the middle.

Comment: Yes, you could either subtract the first letter of the string 'x' with str_sub(x, 0, 1) or define the pattern more narrowly, e.g. "^<"